# git: a clean patch for a branch

Tags: git

Say I have a master branch and a branch for developing a feature:

```
-- s -- x -- x -- x --  HEAD [master]
   \
    \
     bs -- x -- x -- x    [feature]
```

and the feature branch for some reason (laziness) is a bit old. Now when I'm on `master` and do `git diff feature`, I got all the diff from `s` to `HEAD` as well. I'd like to get a diff diff that actually happened on `feature` branch **alone**. But I don't know how to find out what `s` is. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: `git diff s feature`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Jonathon Reinhart noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674865/1256452) you just need to diff commit `s` against the tip of `feature`.  As you noted, you forgot to mention that you want to have git find commit `s` for you.

The general way to ask git to find `s` is to find the "merge base" between `HEAD` (`master`) and `feature`.  The `git merge-base` command does this, so in a shell, you could do:

```
$ s=$(git merge-base HEAD feature)
```

and then

```
$ git diff $s feature
```

Conveniently, though, `git diff` takes over the three-dot syntax: `git diff X...Y` (note the three dots) means "find the merge-base of `X` and `Y` and then diff that merge-base against `Y`".  So:

```
$ git diff master...feature
```

Or, since `HEAD` is currently a symbolic name for `master`, you can write:

```
$ git diff HEAD...feature
```

and this then means that you can simply write:

```
$ git diff ...feature
```

as omitting one of the names means "use `HEAD`".  (Or, if you prefer and your git is not too ancient, you can use `@` to spell `HEAD`.)

Comment: Well written answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the changes from `s` to `feature`, then:

```
git diff s feature
```

From the man page:

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
> ```

For all of your diffing needs, consult http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff